# adc_bridge in ngspice

Tags: ngspice

Why does the adc_bridge not work when we have an input dc value?
The plot for v(1) appears but v(cmp) is blank.

```
.model adc_buff adc_bridge(in_low=0.5 in_high=0.5)
v7 1 0 5
Aad1 [1][cmp] adc_buff
.control
tran 0.02u 7u
plot v(1)
plot v(cmp)
.endc
.end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted the error message as well:

> Unknown model type adc_bridge - ignored

That's the reason you don't see any output for node cmd.

---

Check the manual, chapter 12 of the [manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf)

You will find that `adc_bridge` is a XSPICE extension.

And at the beginning at chapter 12, it reads:

> To make use of the XSPICE extensions, you need to compile them in.

I've no experience with that, but hope you can continue from here.

Comment: I didn't encounter any error while compiling. Moreover the code works completely fine when I replace v7 with a pulse voltage. The problem arises only for a dc input. 
Thanks for replying!